# Postgres CTE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.5

1. I want to insert a new row into a table1 returning the id1.
2. Then using the id1 insert row into table2 returning the id2.
3. Then update table1 with the id2 to create a relation.
4. Finally, use both id1 and id2 to insert into table3.
   I've created a CTE but it doesn't seem to be doing the third step (update table1 with id2). How can I make it do all the steps correctly?

```
with
supply as (
insert into "MOBILE_SUPPLIES" ("NAME", "TYPE") values ('Test2', 1) returning *
),
loc as (
insert into "MOBILE_LOCATIONS" ("LNG", "LAT", "SUPPLY_ID") values (31.232, 31.232, (select "ID" from supply)) returning *
),
up as (
update "MOBILE_SUPPLIES" set "LOCATION_ID"=(select "ID" from loc) where "ID"=(select "ID" from supply) returning *
)
insert into "MOBILE_DATES" ("DATE_FROM", "LOCATION_ID", "SUPPLY_ID") values (current_timestamp, (select "ID" from loc), (select "ID" from supply))
```

Just to clarify my id is accessible by "ID" (it requires the double quotes I know it's not common practice)

Comment: I edited my 4th point to clarify my question but basically the question is how can I make it do all the steps correctly?

Comment: Should step 3 affect the row from step 1? That wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes it's the row from step 1. Why wouldn't it work? Also is there anyway I create a similar CTE that will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed in [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING), modifying a row that you added in the same statement won't work:

> The sub-statements in `WITH` are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in `WITH`, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see [Chapter 13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html)), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that `RETURNING` data is the only way to communicate changes between different `WITH` sub-statements and the main query.

I guess this question is about auto-generated identifiers, and the rows in `"MOBILE_SUPPLIES"` and `"MOBILE_LOCATIONS"` should reference each other.

You could do that by explicitly fetching the sequence value:

```
WITH new_loc_id AS (
   SELECT nextval('"MOBILE_LOCATIONS_ID_seq"') AS "ID"
),
WITH supply AS (
   INSERT INTO "MOBILE_SUPPLIES" ("NAME", "TYPE", "LOCATION_ID")
   SELECT 'Test2', 1, "ID"
   FROM new_loc_id
   RETURNING "ID", "LOCATION_ID"
),
loc AS (
   INSERT INTO "MOBILE_LOCATIONS" ("ID", "LNG", "LAT", "SUPPLY_ID")
   SELECT "LOCATION_ID", 31.232, 31.232, "ID"
   FROM supply
   RETURNING "ID"
)
...
```

Comment: I have fixed the double quotes in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your third step should be a update from:

```
update "MOBILE_SUPPLIES"
set "LOCATION_ID"= my_data.loc_id
from (select loc."ID" as loc_id ,
      supply."ID" as supply_id
      from loc
      inner join supply on loc."SUPPLY_ID" = supply."ID") as my_data
on my_data.supply_id="MOBILE_SUPPLIES"."ID"
returning *
```